CSP worker-src blob:URL
I use Cloudflare's Turnstile to only allow humans. However, as it uses a lot of JavaScript to determine if a human is at the other end or not, I have noticed a bunch of errors in the console related to CSP and tried to fine tune them to have a secure CSP and a clear console.
However, one I cannot get rid of is this one:

Refused to create a worker from 'blob:' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "worker-src 'none'".

I don't want to add blob: there, as it would allow all blobs from anywhere. What I'm looking for is a way to specify 'you're OK to run blob: only from this URL'. But any way I try is in vain. Searching the docs, SO or the Internet also hasn't produced any useful results.
Is that really unsupported? If so, I'll just leave it be, as Turnstile succeeds without blobs, too.
